# prevent sending http post request headers

Tags: jquery, angular, http-headers, angular8

I want to send a raw http request without any header. Just data. I tried jQuery ajax and post functions. I also tried angular 8.

please note that I don't want to set `content-type` to something. I want to completely get rid of it. You can do that with postman

[image: I don't want to send any request header]

Comment: Have you tried `req.headers.delete('Content-Type')`?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It is not a XY problem. I'm asking my problem and showing some methods that I tried and failed. I just want NOT to send any header information when I make an HTTP POST request